# Mac: Notification Center doesn't parse `loc-key` from my Push Notification Payload

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending this to my Mac

```
{"aps":
    {
     "alert":{"loc-key":"F"},
     "sound":"s"
    }
}
```

and for whatever reason, the `loc-key` isn't parsed. I know it's in the Localizable, because if I call `NSLocalizedString(userInfo["aps"]["alert"]["loc-key"])` it works perfectly, saying (for example) `Hello World`.

Also, if I have simply `"alert":"F"`, the Notification says `F`. There's something I might be doing wrong with that `loc-key`. I can't find anywhere an information that would suggest `loc-key` only works on iOS.

The [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) mentions it on the Mac Developer Library just like on iOS.

Comment: Do you mean it is not used for the display in the message center (et al), or is it not present in the user info?

Comment: have you figured it out? faced the same problem

Comment: @Sega-Zero: I worked around it. I even have a thread here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/965534#965534 — To their credits (and to "boo" me!) I just realized I actually never filed a bug on this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this Apple bug is to add an empty "loc-args" array when using "loc-key".

An example JSON string that works for both iOS and OSX is as follows:

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : { 
      "loc-key" : "contact_request", 
      "loc-args" : []
    }, 
    "badge": 8 
  }
}
```